PyQt: transparent background but keep the frame
I want to have the following: a PyQt application with a transparent background, but with the "frame" still visible. With frame I mean a border which you can use to resize, the titlebar and also the close and minimize button. With transparent I mean that you can see "through" the application, i.e. you can see the program that's behind the PyQt application.
Here's what I tried:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout,
    QLabel
    )
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QPainter, QBrush, QColor, QPen
    )
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QPoint, Qt, QSize

#%%

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(30,30,600,400)

        # These lines try to make the background transparent
        self.setWindowOpacity(.8)
        self.setStyleSheet("background:red;")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_PaintOnScreen)
        # self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight) 
        self.button = QPushButton("X")
        self.button.setFixedSize(QSize(40, 40))
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.close)
  
        self.show()
        self.setFocus()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

Some comments on the lines I used.
self.setWindowOpacity(.8)

This line works, but it makes the titlebar transparent with the same amount. If I want to have full transparency, the titlebar would be invisible as well.
    self.setStyleSheet("background:red;")

Some sources stated that this line would work, but it doesn't seem to. It just makes it black. I put it to red here, so the button is visible at least.
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground)
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_PaintOnScreen)

These lines don't seem to do anything
self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

These lines work if used together, but they make everything disappear. Including the titlebar and the frame.
Any thoughts?

Playing around for some time and couldn't find a work around. Seems like we have no direct access to window frame or I might be wrong

@Brawldude2 that would be sad. I'm thinking about implementing a workaround using framelesswindow + implementing resizing by hand

You need to use setMask(). Just create an empty QRegion and then add to it a QRegion for the geometry() of each direct child. All this has to be done within the resizeEvent() override, and you shall also remove all setWindowFlags() and setAttribute() lines.
